# facing error while creating setup in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-express

A dialog window relating to SQL Management Studio appears with the following

Please wait while Windows configures SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Management Studio.
On top of that dialog window a further dialog window appears with:

0: Watson 1: 1304 2: STreamSupportFiles 3:streamBinaryToDisk 4:5 5:e:\sql10_main_t\sql\setup\darmwin\sqlcastub\streamca.cpp 6:238 7:sqlcastub.dll 8:sqlrun.msi

above error facing while creating setup in visual studio 2017,
when i click ok then error message come access denied and one installer window runs for a log while
 im using visual studio 2017 professional and sql server 2008 express

Comment: Try starting SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and see if that runs.  It comes with the SQL Server.   If it does run make note of the instance of the SQL Server in the login window.  The check the connection string for the SQL Server in your project.  It may be in a configuration xml file.  Make sure the instance is the same in SSMS and your c# application.  Also make sure the connection string does not contain the mdf file name.  The server owns the mdf file and cannot be accessed by the mdf file.  I think this changed in difference versions of SQL Server.

Comment: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/119940/sql-2008-r2-sp3-install-error.html

Comment: error facing in visual studio 2017 while crating client setup @stuartd

Comment: So? It's the **exact same error**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

heyy after long time i got a same solution on microsoft as well as stack overflow

here it is

```
regsvr32.exe /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
 regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
```

note-open cmd with administration.