# VS2019 Setup Project Build Error (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, setup-project, visual-studio-2019, build-error

I am attempting to Build a Setup Project in VS2019 and I immediately get the following prompts:

0:Watson 1:1304 2:StreamSupportFiles 3:streamBinaryToDisk

[image]

Error writing to file. Access is denied

[image]

This has stumped me as I am not using SQL Server 2008 anywhere in C# my Project!

Any suggestions anyone has would be gratefully appreciated!

Cheers,

Steve.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found the answer here: [facing error while creating setup in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379719/facing-error-while-creating-setup-in-visual-studio-2017)

Open "cmd" with Administrator privileges and:

regsvr32.exe /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"

Steve.

Comment: This was EXACTLY the same problem I had and your solution fixed it. Thank you!